# Storing any type of data in a node using void pointer(Could be int char or a structure)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct genericStorage
{
  void *data;
  int type;
};


struct genericNode
{
  struct genericStorage storage;
  struct genericNode *next;
};

struct genericNode *new,*temp;

struct genericNode* createGLL(int type)
{
  int a;
  char b;


  if(type==0)
    {
      new=(struct genericNode *) malloc (sizeof(struct genericNode));
      (new->storage).data=(int *) malloc (sizeof(int));
      printf("Enter Integer");
      scanf("%d",&a);
      *((int *)(new->storage.data))=a;
      new->storage.type=type;
      new->next=NULL;

    }
  else if(type==1)
    {
      new=(struct genericNode *) malloc (sizeof(struct genericNode));
      (new->storage).data=(char *) malloc (sizeof(char));
      printf("Enter Char");
      scanf("%c",&b);
      *((char *)(new->storage.data))='c';
      new->storage.type=type;
      new->next=NULL;

    }
    else if(type==2)
    {
      new=(struct genericNode *) malloc (sizeof(struct genericNode));
      temp=(struct genericNode *) malloc (sizeof(struct genericNode));
      temp=createGLL(1);
      (new->storage).data=(struct genericNode *)temp;
      new->storage.type=type;
      new->next=NULL;
    }
}

void print(struct genericNode *t)
{
  if(t->storage.type==0)
    printf("%d\n",*(int *)t->storage.data);
  if(t->storage.type==1)
    printf("%c\n",*(char *)t->storage.data);
  if(t->storage.type==2)
    printf("%c\n",*(struct genericNode *)(t->storage.data->(temp->storage).data));

}

int main()
{
  int type;

  struct genericNode *head;
  head=NULL;
  printf("Enter the type");
  scanf("%d",&type);
  getchar();
  head=createGLL(type);
  print(head);
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting a problem in the print function where I have to print the data stored inside a structure which is stored in an outer structure. How can I access the data in the inner structure and print it? Please Help needed urgently.

Comment: It gives me an error
linkedlistvoid.c: In function ‘print’:
linkedlistvoid.c:65:60: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
rutuparna@pucsd-rutuparna:~/C/Datastructures assignment$

Comment: This code is odd. What do you want to use `type` for? And why do you allocate space for an `int` if you want to store a generic type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> (t->storage.data->(temp->storage).data)
> ```

This line makes no sense. You are trying to access a member in storage.data but instead of a valid member's name you have another access to a member in `temp`. It's simply not C.

If I understand your code `t->storage.data` might be another pointer to a `genericNode`. In that case you might want to do instead:

```
if(t->storage.type == 2) {
    struct genericNode *node = t->storage.data;
    printf("Jumping to the inner genericNode at %p\n", (void *)node);

    print(node); /* Call print again. */
}
```